# What protocol do POS devices use to communicate?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, point-of-sale

What is the name of the protocol which POS (point of sales) devices, such as credit card payment device, use to communicate over network?

Can anyone please describe the networking of those devices? A link to specifications would be appreciated. What ports are used? How data is packed/serialized?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rs-232 over a serial port or a usb device to connect through your PC. If you have a network device that have an IP address it will be TCP-IP.

Answer (score 1):

X.25 or PPP over GPRS. Take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service#Protocols_supported).